# `The standard deviation is zero` error with cor function calling in group_by

Tags: r, debugging, error-handling, dplyr, try-catch

```
df <- data.frame(Tag = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
             x = c(9,7,3,2,1,1,1,1),
             y = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4))

cor_fun<- function(x,y){
           val <- cor(x,y)
           return(val)}

df %>%
group_by(Tag) %>%
  summarise(c = cor_fun(x,y))
```

Here we are trying to compute correlation between `x` & `y` by `group_by`(Tag).the problem is when we compute correlation for x & y and , any one of the columns has standard deviation 0 it spits error of 
`the standard deviation is zero` which is not acceptable in production. so what I except is whenever `the standard deviation is zero` occurs the function should return mean of x else correlation output should be returned.i have tried reproducing the same scenario which is pasted below please guide me on this.
**using try-catch** in Function name `cor_fun`.

**Brief Requirement**

1. Inside Function, we can use try-catch function and look for  `the standard deviation is zero` this error,
2. If `the standard deviation is zero` this error occurs Function shall return mean of x.
3. If an error is not found then return `cor(x,y)` output.

[image: Here the screen shot of error message]

Expected is no error message instead function should return mean of x value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just precalculate standard deviation and if it fails the check, return mean of x.

```
cor_fun<- function(x,y){

  if (any(sapply(list(x, y), FUN = sd) == 0)) {
    return(mean(x))
  } else {
    val <- cor(x,y)
    return(val)
  }
}

df %>%
  group_by(Tag) %>%
  summarise(c = cor_fun(x,y))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
    Tag      c
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 -0.977
2     2  1
```

If you want to go the `tryCatch` route, you could do

```
cor_fun<- function(x,y){
  val <- tryCatch(cor(x, y), error = function(e) e, warning = function(w) w)
  if (any(class(val) %in% c("simpleWarning", "warning"))) {
    return(mean(x))
  } else {
    return(val)
  }
}
```

`tryCatch` evaluates an expression, in your case `cor(x, y)`. If the expression returns an error or warning, it will store that error in `val` and move on to the next line. If the expression evaluates as expected, it will be stored in `val` like nothing happened. When an error or warning occur, the class of `val` changes from expected e.g. `numeric` to `simpleWarning` or `simpleError`. I use that to catch if evaluation of the expression failed and handle it. This handling could also be done inside the `function(e) e` call.

Here's handling the warning witnin the `tryCatch` call.

```
cor_fun<- function(x,y){
  val <- tryCatch(cor(x, y), 
                  error = function(e) e,
                  warning = function(w) {
                    # in case there is a warning (for whatever reason)
                    # return mean of x
                    return(mean(x))
                  })
  val
}
```

You can read more in the `?tryCatch` documentation or e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r).

Comment: .! Thank you for replying. can you please explain tryCatch code:

Comment: @Harvey sure, see my comment. Note that documentation for `tryCatch` is not the worst. There are also other online resources you could go through to understand this bit.